# External HDD doesn't show up in finder/disk utility, but shows up in System Information

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I have a HDD that's corrupted. I don't know what caused the corruption, but it's definitely corrupted (it makes strange sounds when plugged in).

When I plug it in to my mac via USB-C, it does not show up in finder and disk utility, but in System Information -> USB, I can see the name of my external HDD in the USB Device Tree. I'm a bit confused about what this means given that it does seem to be partially recognized by my macbook?

Comment: In Disk Utility enable the menu item View > Show all devices. Does the disk appear now?

Comment: @Gilby I can try, but I'm hesitant to keep plugging it in (a data recovery person told me the more I plug it in the more corrupted it becomes). If it doesn't show up in Finder, doesn't this indicate it won't show up in disk utility regardless of whether that option is enabled?

Comment: Finder only shows successfully mounted file systems. Disk Utility shows mounted and mountable file systems, but (unless you enable Show all devices) it does not show disks without mountable file systems. Hence I suggested enabling show all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Something happened to your HDD to cause this failure.

The data recovery person telling you that the more you plug it in the more corrupted it becomes is likely correct.

Ask the data recovery guy for a quote. FYI it is likely to be more expensive than you think or will want to pay. There is a reason for that, recovering data from hard drives is as much art as it is science. And the people who do it (for reputable companies) are very skilled technicians.

I had to have this done once on a Dell Poweredge server with a big RAID array, at 3AM. I ran some remote control software on the system and the guy got to work. It cost the company about $5K for an hour or two of work. That was in 2003.

The company happily paid to recover the data and then upgraded our backup software/system.

If I were you I would stop plugging the drive into anything, get a quote for data recovery and upgrade your backup system to avoid these issues in the future.

Note, I am recommending this as a wise course of action. There may be others that have a solution that is less expensive, and perhaps even more wise.

Comment: Yeah I got a quote and it's $2k lol. I want the data but not that bad. I have other ways to reproduce the data, it just takes time. I'm taking a crack at it myself to see if I can recover it. I just removed the casing and going to see if I can figure out the issue. It's not a huge deal if I break it (for the same reason why I don't want to pay $2k to get the data off)